# how to fix session in json using flask

Tags: session

I'm new to programming language and I'm not able use session it says attribute error, can some one help me with it 
can some one help what is the exact mistake in my code
actually I'm creating a database table and performing the crud operations. and using the url to check my output in postman 
can some one help

this is my code:

---

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
import os
import requests
import sqlite3



app = Flask(__name__)
dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(dir,'crud.sqlite')
employee = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)


class employee(db.Model):
    e_id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    e_name = db.Column(db.String(120),unique=True)
    email  = db.Column(db.String(180),unique=True)

    def __init__(self,e_name,email):
        self.e_name = e_name
        self.email = email

class Schema(ma.Schema):
    class meta:
        fields = ('e_name','email')

schema = Schema()
schema = Schema(many = True)   

@app.route('/',methods = ["POST"])
def insert():
    e_name = request.json
    print (e_name)
    # e_name = request.json['e_name']
    email = request.json
    print (email)
    new_entry = employee(e_name,email)
    db.Session.add(new_entry)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify(new_entry)

@app.route('/employee',methods = ["GET"])
def select():
    select_employee = employee.query.all()
    result = schema.dump(select_employee)
    return jsonify(result.data)


@app.route('/employee/<id>',methods = ["GET"])
def select_by_id(id):
    employee = employee.query.get(id)
    return schema.jsonify(employee)

@app.route('/employee/<id>',methods= ["GET"])
def update(id):
    employee = employee.query.get(id)
    e_name = request.json['e_name']
    email = request.json['email']

    employee.e_name = e_name
    employee.email = email
    db.session.commit()
    return schema.jsonify(employee)


@app.route("/employee/<id>",methods=["DELETE"])
def delete(id):
    employee = employee.query.get(id)
    db.session.delete(employee)
    db.session.commit()
    return schema.jsonify(employee)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

---

db.Session.add(new_entry)
TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'instance'

Comment: Sounds legit: the object `employee` does not have that attribute. So why do you expect that code to work?

Comment: I made a mistake of specifying class name and object name as employee so it was treating both as one

Comment: but got an another error.: db.Session.add(new_entry)  :TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'instance'

Comment: So, you probably want to share the adjusted code and the new error?

Comment: updated new code and error